# Как бы вы выделили основы в предложениях?

Tags: сказуемые

> Киви имеет хорошие вкусовые свойства.
> Мальчик имеет талант.

Распространили бы вы сказуемое в данных примерах? Почему?

Comment: В таких случаях "есть" употребляется.

Comment: В каком смысле?

Comment: *У мальчика есть талант.* Либо без глагола: *У киви хорошие вкусовые свойства.* А у вас стилистика нарушена, так не говорят, режет слух.